# graph-tool Collect Vertex Marginals - pv Size

Tags: graph-tool

I was running

> gt.mcmc_equilibrate(state, force_niter=300, mcmc_args=dict(niter=10), 
>                           callback=collect_vertex_marginals)

And I got a Property Map (let's call it pv) of the vertex marginals.  The pv gives an array for each vertex, say, [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 299.0], which I understand is that it counts how many times the vertex was in a block (in this case, all counts would be in block 3), so the vertex is assigned to block 3 as it has the highest probability of being in there.

So... is it that the nth element in the array is also the the nth block?

I thought that this was the case but got pv[some vertice] which had array sizes which were smaller than the block number.

So... how should I interpret the vertex_marginals property map? 
Your help is very much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrays are resized on demand to avoid unnecessary memory usage. For each inexistent entry, you can assume that the corresponding value is zero.